# Is the letter attributed to have been sent by Muhammad to the Byzantine Emperor authentic?

Tags: political-history, religion, islam

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad's_letters_to_the_Heads-of-State) shows a letter that is claimed be sent from Muhammad to the Emperor of Byzantine Empire.

But it doesn't have any information about authenticity of the letter as in if it is actually the real letter sent to the Basileus by the Islamic Prophet.

Is it authentic? Is it accepted as authentic by historians?

After searching the internet for a while, I found this video ([Original Letters of Prophet Muhammad](https://youtu.be/JB5R1a4bSUM?t=2m19s)) which shows a letter (at 2.19) that seems to be different from the letter shown in the Wikipedia page cited above. The video claims the letter shown in the video is authentic (at 2.35).

Which one is authentic? The one shown in the video or the one shown in the Wikipedia page? Are they both authentic (maybe Muhammad sent both letters)?

Comment: There appears to be some controversy concerning the authenticity of the letter. [El-Chiekh](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=QC03pKNpfaoC&pg=PA43&dq=muhammad%27s+letter+to+byzantine+emperor&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju9vnTy9TQAhUDabwKHdNLDkoQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=muhammad's%20letter%20to%20byzantine%20emperor&f=false) goes into some detail in her book about it. Most of the information about this comes from Arabic and Islamic sources.

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Haven't DV'd myself but If I were to venture a guess, i'd say that's because your question asks if it is authentic but doesn't provide any info as to why would you doubt it's authenticity?

Comment: This is kind of like "Wikipedia says Allies won WW2. But I see no information about the authenticity of this conclusion. Do historians accept it?". It would be a good question if you were to show your research as to why you don't believe Wikipedia article isn't authentic enough and why would you tend to believe otherwise

Comment: Also I'd say that such an embassy was sent. After all, the [Battle of Mutah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mu%27tah) was a result of attack on the emissary of Muhammad. As to if the Letter shown in the article, No idea if it's the same one sent to the Basileus.

Comment: @NSNoob Research added.

Comment: To be clear, Are you asking if the letter is authentic, as in the real one sent to the Basileus by Muhammad? Or are you asking if Muhammad actually sent an emissary to deliver his letter?

Comment: @NSNoob Whether the letter is authentic as in the real one sent to the Basileus by Muhammad.

Comment: I really appreciate the work you've done to document the research on this question. Questions like this help me to **learn** history.

Comment: They are at least as authentic as the Shroud of Turin or the relics of the True Cross.

Comment: AFAIK, correct me if I'm wrong, isn't Muhammad illiterate? Thus it'd be difficult (if not impossible) to tell if the letter was really from him or not since we don't have a sample of hia writings to compare it to.

Comment: @AyaseEri There are many ways we can conclude that it's from Muhammad. He didn't wrote the letters. His scribes reportedly wrote them and he signed them with his seal. Search "seal of muhammad" to see the seal. If the letter is carbon dated to that period and have the same seal as other letters sent by Muhammad, then it would be quite logical to assume it's from Muhammad. The video l linked mentions a study. I think finding that study will solve the question.